# Sending data from arduino through bluetooth serial

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, microcontroller, arduino-ide

I’m currently trying to design a controller that would communicate through Bluetooth to an android phone (Galaxy Nexus). I’m facing a few challenges. Also, I don’t have much practical programming experience.

At the core of the controller resides an Arduino microcontroller who scans the state of 8 digital pins and six analogue pins (10 bits) and sends the data through serial, to an HC-05 Bluetooth chip.
The android phone should then read the serial information sent through Bluetooth and either transmit the packet to another phone - That will take me a while to implement as I know very little of how the internet works - or analyse and interpret it for further action to be taken

What I’m asking for are insight as to the best way to go about doing this. Now what does best mean? 
We’ll I want it to be real time so when I press a button or  a combination of bottoms, boom, the android phone takes action fast enough for a human not to perceive a delay.

Then I want to be able to associate the information the phone reads in the serial buffer to the corresponding button or analogue pin. In case there is an error or to avoid that they fall out of sync

Here is what I have so far. I have not tested this code yet, partly because I’m still learning how to program the android part of this project, partly because I want some feedback as to whether I’m being silly or this is actually an effective way to go about doing this:

```
//Initialization
/*

This Program has three functions:
1) Scan 8 digital pins and compile their state in a single byte ( 8 bits)
2) Scans 6 Analogue inputs corresponding to the joysticks and triggers 
3) Send this info as packets through seril --> Bluetooth 

*/
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>// import the serial software library

#define A = 2
#define B = 3
#define X = 4
#define Y = 5
#define LB = 6
#define RB = 7
#define LJ = 8
#define RJ = 9
#define RX = 10
#define TX = 11
//Pin 12 and 13 are unused for now
SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(RX,TX); //Setup software serial using the defined constants
// declare other variables
byte state = B00000000

void setup() {
  //Setup code here, to run once:
  //Setup all digital pin inputs
  pinMode(A,INPUT);
  pinMode(B,INPUT);
  pinMode(X,INPUT);
  pinMode(Y,INPUT);
  pinMode(LB,INPUT);
  pinMode(RB,INPUT);
  pinMode(LJ,INPUT);
  pinMode(RJ,INPUT);
  //Setup all analogue pin inputs
  //setup serial bus and send validation message
  Bluetooth.begin(9600);
  Bluetooth.println("The controller has successfuly connected to the phone")
}

void loop() {
  //Main code here, to run repeatedly: 
  //Loop to sum digital inputs in a byte, left shift the byte every time by 1 and add that if the pin is high
  for(byte pin = 2, b = B00000001;  pin < 10; pin++, b = b << 1){ if (digitalRead(pin)== HIGH) state += b; }
  //Send digital state byte to serial
  Bluetooth.write(state);
  //Loop to read analgue pin 0 to 5 and send it to serial
  for( int pin = 0, testByte = 0x8000; pin < 6 ; pin++, testByte = testByte >> 1) { Bluetooth.write(analogRead(pin)+testByte); }
}

//Adding some validation would be wise. How would I go about doing that?
// Could add a binary value of 1000_0000_0000_0000,  0100_0000_0000_0000,  0010_0000_0000_0000 ... so on and then use a simple AND statement at the other end to veryfy what analogue reading the info came from
// so say the value for analgue is 1023 and came from analgue pin 1 I would have 0100_0011_1111_1111 now using an bitwise && I could check it against 0100_0000_0000_0000 if the result is 0100_0000_0000_0000 then I know this is the analogu reading from pin 1
//could easily implement a test loop with a shiting bit on the android side
```

Is it pointless for me to be doing bit shifts like this? Ultimately, if I’m not mistaken, all data is sent as bytes ( 8 bits packets) so will the `Bluetooth.write(analogRead(pin)+testByte)` actually send two bytes or will it truncate the `int` data? how will it be broken down and how can I recuperate it on the android end?

How would you go about implementing this? Any insights or words of advice?

Answer (score 3):

It's great that you are learning this!  Some suggestions:

Your code will be easier to read, understand and maintain if you space it out a bit, particularly by adding newlines...

```
void loop() {
  //Main code here, to run repeatedly: 
  //Loop to sum digital inputs in a byte, 
  //left shift the byte every time by 1 and add that  if the pin is high
  for( byte pin = 2, b = B00000001;  pin < 10; pin++, b = b << 1) {
    if (digitalRead(pin)== HIGH)
      state += b;
  }
  //Send digital state byte to serial
  Bluetooth.write(state);
  //Loop to read analgue pin 0 to 5 and send it to serial
  for( int pin = 0, testByte = 0x8000; pin < 6 ; pin++, testByte = testByte >> 1) {
    Bluetooth.write(analogRead(pin)+testByte); 
  }
}
```

Also, you can use the shift operators with values other than one.  so instead of keeping a shift mask that you then add in, you just use the a simple variable.   A more classic way to do what you expressing in the first looop would be something like this:

```
#define PIN_OFFSET 2
  for ( int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (digitalRead( i+PIN_OFFSET)== HIGH)
      state += (1 << i);
  }
```

The second loop could be done similarly:

```
  for( int pin = 0; pin < 6; pin++) {
    short testByte = 0x8000 >> pin;
    short result =  analogRead(pin) + testByte;
    Bluetooth.write( result >> 8); 
    Bluetooth.write( result & 0xFF); 
  }
```

Note that the Bluetooth.write() call sends a byte, so this code sends first the most significant byte, then the least.

Lastly, you probably want to zero your state variable at be beginning of loop() -- otherwise, once a bit is set it will never get cleared.

You may want to think about what you are sending to the phone.  It will be binary data, and that can be difficult to deal with -- how do you know the start and end, and often a value will be misinterpretted as a control character messing you up big time.  Consider changing it into a formatted, human readable string, with a newline at the end.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and encouragement @bobwki! I'll definetly keep that in mind. Alright, so you suggest that I send more "formatted human readeable string". Will the computation of that still be fast enough to be real time? That's really my only issue and the reason why im trying to be really efficient with the amount of data i send around and crunch.

Comment: Not sure about the efficiency issue -- Another approach would be to encode the results so at least it is printable characters, to avoid the control code problems.   Also, note that you cannot assume that Bluetooth will be able to take characters as fast as you can send them.  It will buffer the characters and send them as best it can.  Depending on how the interface works (I haven't looked), it may throw away chars it can't send, or it will do some kind of "flow control" -- both of which may not be good for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino end of this is more than fast enough to do what you want to do and you need not worry in the slightest about minimising the number of bytes you send out from the micro to the phone when you're talking about such a tiny amount of data. I'm not quite clear what you're sending to the phone; are you wanting a different value for each button so when a button is pressed it sends out something like:

Button Was Pressed, Button Number (Two bytes)

And if it's an analogue value:

Analogue Value Read, Analogue Value MSB, Analogue Value LSB (assuming the analogue value is greater than eight bits

I don't know the Arduino code you're using, but my suspicion is that this line:

Bluetooth.write(analogRead(pin)+testByte)

Would send one byte which is the addition of the analogue value and whatever testByte is.

Would you be able to post a link to the documentation for this API?

Any delay with all this will come at the phone end. Please don't concern yourself in the slightest about trying to save a byte or two at the Arduino end! (I'm currently doing a project with a Cortex M3 sending data via a Bluetooth module to Android phones and we're shipping several k of data around. I know from this experience the difference between two and twenty bytes is not of consequence in terms of delay.)

Comment: Ok, thanks, good to know I don't have to worry about speed then! And then I wouldn't need the test byte if I have a "Button pressed" sent before. The API can be found on the arduino website. http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage#.UxLULfldVjQ

Answer (score 0):

It may be good for you to opt for ready available bluetooth terminal apps for your android handset. On Google play, few apps are:
1) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=arduino.bluetooth.terminal&hl=en
2) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sena.bterm&hl=en
(and few more are availble on Google play).This will help you to focus only on controller side development.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already downloaded a terminal to test whether my blutooth module was working or not. That said, A terminal app is pointless since all they do is display the data sent through the terminal. If I want to process that data, I'll need to modify their code or write an app from scratch. In both cases I need to learn the android part of things. Which i'm totally fine with! the whole purpose of this project is the give me good excuse to make the effort necessary to learn something. =)